# Kohana framework Fatal error mystery

Tags: kohana, php

I got a fatal error at auto_load function. See the following error, indicating that the specific directory and file '/mnt/webDir/www/sossage/system/classes/kohna/log.php' file failed opening required. Yes, file doesn't exist. Its's wrong path.
But, I never write the code, also can't find anywhere using 'find' option on my web root.

> Fatal error:  Kohana_Core::auto_load(): Failed opening required '/mnt/webDir/www/mysite/system/classes/kohna/log.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /mnt/webDir/mysite/system/classes/kohana/core.php on line 418, referer:

How can I solve the problem, please let me know the solution or tips.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a fresh Kohana install?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. 
Yes, never upgraded. It's a fresh install, Kohana 3.0.4 and never touch anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in your configuration, likely. Note the directory it's attempting to access:

```
...system/classes/kohna/log.php
```

"kohna" is not the appropriate spelling. The directory is instead:

```
...system/classes/kohana/
```

[image]